# Android Logcat prune function is broken?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

Used the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat), and also verified the command help string within the source to make sure it's not out of date.

```
$ adb logcat --pid=1792
--------- beginning of main
01-16 14:34:19.299  1792  2285 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
01-16 14:34:19.299  1792  2285 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
01-16 14:34:20.299  1792  2285 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
...

$ adb logcat -P '"~/1792"'
$ adb logcat --prune
~/1792

$ adb logcat
01-16 14:37:53.312  1792  2285 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
01-16 14:37:53.312  1792  2285 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
01-16 14:37:54.312  1792  2285 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
01-16 14:37:54.312  1792  2285 E GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
```

I'm trying to blacklist the PID responsible for the Gnss log spam, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm on the Android emulator and running ADB as root.

Comment: I'm having problems getting it to work as well - but should you be using 1792 in your case rather than 1762?

Comment: @SparkyNZ, yes, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this feature is now removed. I never got it working.